# How to set the text alignment of MS table column according to data types?

Tags: c#, ms-word

I've tried to display the values of properties from a list of class on the table of MS Word like this:

```
public void CreateTable<T>(IList<T> list)
{
    if (list != null)
    {
        var props = typeof(T).GetProperties();

        Range tableLoc = WdDoc.Range();            

        var table = WdDoc.Tables.Add(tableLoc, list.Count, props.Length);  

        for (int i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
        {
            table.Columns[i + 1].Select();                    
            if (props[i].PropertyType == typeof(double))
            {                        
                WdApp.Selection.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphRight;
            }
            else
            {                        
                WdApp.Selection.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
            }
        }

        //...
    }
}
```

I tried to automatically set the text alignment of columns according to fill-in property type. 
However, only the first row of each column can be set as the correct alignment I assign.
Other rows will always be set as the latest alignment of for loop.
Why did this happen? Did I miss any snippet?

Also, what are the differences between

```
WdApp.Selection.Paragraphs.Format.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
```

and

```
WdApp.Selection.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from using `Selection.Range` in this specific instance of working with the Word object model. When working with columns you need to use

```
WdApp.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment
```

**Background**

`Selection` affects exactly what is selected - the entire column.

`Selection.Range` affects the *Range* of the selection. In the case of a Column, Selection.Range can*not* be the entire column. A Range in Word must be a contiguous run of text, but a column is NOT contiguous. So `Selection.Range` returns only that part of the selection that is contiguous: the first cell (row). That explains why only the first row of the table is affected by your current code.

While a selected column *appears* to be contiguous this is just a convenience for the user. Under the covers, everything in the rows between the cells in one column and the next breaks up the text run.

If you're familiar with HTML think of how a table is defined in HTML. The way Word Open XML defines a table works on the same principle. The concept looks something like this:

```
<table><row><cell><cell></row><row><cell><cell><row></table>
```

The rows and their content are contiguous.